# Dynamic menu with symfony layout

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I started using symfony a few weeks ago, and there are some things that are not clear for me.

My question is that how could I put a list of categories (for menu) in the main layout of an application? How can I pass a variable for this layout and where to put this variable? I don't want to put it in every module.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read about components, slots and partials? Start here: http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_code_fragments

And here's the best menu plugin ever: http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ioMenuPlugin

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass variables for the layout. Instead you can use partials or components.